# Pass array written in template to meteor/handlebars helper

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js

I have a helper called `printArray` that just prints every item in an array.  It works great when I define the array in JS and pass it in to the helper via a context object.  What I want to do is define the array right in the template, like:

```
{{printArray arr=[1, 3, 4] }}
```

Unfortunately, by the time this gets to my helper, the `arr` key points to `undefined`.  Is there any valid syntax to get the array inside my helper without defining it in javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use another helper that returns an array

```
Template.ArrayDemo.helpers({
    arrayValues: [1, 2, 3],
    printArray: function(arr) {
        for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            console.log(arr[i]);
        }
    }
 });
```

now you can do

`{{printArray arr=arrayValues}}`

Answer (score 8):

You can use JavaScript's `arguments` array to accomplish something like this. The `arguments` array gives you access to every value passed to the function when it is called.

This will allow you to use syntax like this:

```
{{printArray 1 3 4}}
```

The code looks like this:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('printArray', function() {
    //Last argument is the options object.
    var options = arguments[arguments.length - 1];

    //Skip the last argument.
    for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length - 1; ++i) {
        //Do your thing with each array element.
    }

    //Return your results...
    return '';
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can almost accomplish this with the use of `eval()`, using a helper like this:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('printArray', function(values) {
   var array = eval(values);

   if (array.constructor === Array()) {
     ...
   }
}
```

The above allows you to call this from the template:

```
{{printArray '[0, 1, 2]'}}
```

The one caveat to this method is that you have to pass your array as a string.

Answer (score 2):

Helper:

```
printArray: (...options) => {
        // remove unneeded properties
        options.pop();
        
        // return option array
        return options;
}
```

Template:

```
{{printArray "banana" "apple" "orange" "kiwi"}}
```

Returns:

```
["banana", "apple", "orange", "kiwi"]
```

You can use it in conjunction with other helpers:

```
{{#each (printArray "banana" "apple" "orange" "kiwi")}}
         {{this}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried passing in just the bracketed value of the array?

```
{{printArray [1, 3, 4]}}
```

I know you can easily pass in objects, as arguments to the handlebars helper methods:

```
{{printArray {arr: [1, 3, 4]} }}
```

Take a look at these awesome helper methods, most of which I stole from elsewhere, a few of which I wrote or tweaked... They are my reference starting point on the topic:

https://github.com/zeroasterisk/Presenteract/blob/master/client/lib/handlebar-helpers.js

Comment: These look awesome, but I must be misunderstanding something - I get `Expecting 'CLOSE', 'DATA', 'STRING', 'INTEGER', 'BOOLEAN', 'ID', 'SEP', got 'INVALID'` on the opening curly brace of the object.  Could this syntax be allowed in plain Handlebars but disallowed in meteor?

Comment: Thanks for the link to your code.  Can you point out where you're _using_ these helpers?

Comment: Here's an example of `getSession` https://github.com/zeroasterisk/Presenteract/blob/master/client/views/about.html#L68

Answer (score 1):

You can define a array helper as below.

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('array', function() {
    return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0, -1);
}

{{printArray (array 1 3 4)}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{{printArray '1,3,4'}}

Handlebars.registerHelper("printArray", function(values){
    let array = values.split(",");
    console.log(array);
});
```

Comment: Consider adding more explanation about the code, answers should provide more explanation about the code to make the answer more useful and are more likely to attract upvotes